# Express + PassportJS can't read flash messages

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, flash, passport.js

I have my Express + Passport + Firebase project where I handle authentication with a local stratetegy. Since I found that Passport would take care of the authentication process, so I also found that it would accept flash messages as third parameter for the `done()` function (in the strategy). But I am not sure how to read them:

I guess the flow I made to set and read flash messages were:

1. Install [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) with NPM.
2. Set the Express middleware after importing it:

```js
import * as flash from 'connect-flash';
...
const app = express();
...
app.use(flash());
```

3. Configure Passport Authentication in the Express route according to the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/):

```js
// POST - /api/v1/admin/oauth/login
router.post(
    '/login',
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => { /* middleware function to validate input */ },
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/api/v1/admin/oauth/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }),
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => { /* function after success login */
);
```

4. Include the flash messages in the `done()` method, according to [Passport configuration documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/):

```js
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
import db from '../../config/database';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export default new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, async (email, password, done) => {
    const ref = db.collection('users').doc(email);
    try {
        const doc = await ref.get();
        if (!doc.exists) {
            return done(null, false, { error: 'Wrong email' });
        }

        const user = doc.data();

        const match: boolean = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!match) {
            return done(null, false, { error: 'Wrong password' });
        }

        user.id = doc.id;
        delete user.password;

        return done(null, user);

    } catch(error) {
        return done(error);
    }
});
```

5. Read the flash messages using `req.flash('error')`:

```js
// GET - /api/v1/admin/oauth/login
router.get('/login', (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const result: IResult = {
        message: '',
        data: null,
        ok: false
    };
    if (req.flash('error')) {
        resultado.message = req.flash('error');
        console.log(req.flash('error'));
    }
    return res.status(400).json(result);
});
```

I thought it was theroically working in my mind, until step 5, where `req.flash('error')` has an empty array in it. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Flash messages are only available for the lifetime of a request. Making a `HTTP POST` request to `/login` gets auths the use and flashes a message that can either be rendered appropriately in response to the `HTTP POST` request. The `HTTP GET` request is a separate request and doesn't retrieve the flashed message in the other `HTTP POST` request.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule that's not correct. The flash messages are stored in the session and are available on subsequent requests.

Comment: That's the documented behaviour for flash messages. The documentation must be wrong then.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule source? Documentation reads "Using flash messages requires a req.flash() function." When using `connect-flash` to provide the `req.flash()` function, per the question, the flash messages are stored in the session. [1](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) [2](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash#express-3x)

Comment: I was actually wrong. flashed messages are cookied and available in subsequent requests but can only be read one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep searching and I found a solution but it works in the second login attempt.

#### Steps from my question I modified to make it work:

1. Install [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) with NPM.
2. Set the Express middleware after importing it:

```js
import * as flash from 'connect-flash';
...
const app = express();
...
app.use(flash());
```

3. Configure Passport Authentication in the Express route according to the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/):

```js
// POST - /api/v1/admin/oauth/login
router.post(
    '/login',
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => { /* middleware function to validate input */ },
    passport.authenticate('local', { 
        failureFlash: true,
        failureRedirect: '/api/v1/admin/oauth/login' 
    }),
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => { /* function after success login */
);
```

4. Create another route so it can display the flash message, thanks to @Codebling:

```js
// GET - /api/v1/admin/oauth/login
router.get('/login', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const result: IResult = {
        message: 'Auth ok',
        data: null,
        ok: true
    };

    let status: number = 200;
    const flashMessage: any = req.flash('error');

    if (flashMessage.length) {
        resultado.message = flashMessage[0];
        resultado.ok = false;
        status = 400; 
    }

    return res.status(status).json(result);
});
```

5. Include the flash messages in the `done()` method, according to [Passport configuration documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/):

```js
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
import db from '../../config/database';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export default new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, async (email, password, done) => {
    const ref = db.collection('users').doc(email);
    try {
        const doc = await ref.get();
        if (!doc.exists) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong email' });
        }

        const user = doc.data();

        const match: boolean = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!match) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password' });
        }

        user.id = doc.id;
        delete user.password;

        return done(null, user);

    } catch(error) {
        return done(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you say "only works on the second login attempt"? This is how flash messages work. Usually you would `failureRedirect` to a page which displayed the flash message.

Comment: I get it, my mistake. Is not an option checking the flash message in the preauthentication process since it will be read the flash message only the second time. So I have to use `failureRedirect` always. Then it works the first time. I shouldn't thank you again... but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the flash message wrong!

The 3rd argument of `done()` should be an object with the fields `type` and `message`:

```
return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong email' });
```

The type defaults to `error`.

This API doesn't seem to be documented explicitly, but is shown in the [3rd example of the *Verify Callback* section](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/#verify-callback) in the *Configure* chapter of the Passport.js documentation.

I've created [a repo](https://github.com/codebling/so-express-passport-flash) with a minimally reproducible working example.

Comment: I have tried that and is not working... for saying that what I've tried is wrong you should read [Passport documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/) where it does not mention anything regarding an specific object name. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Maramal I've updated the answer. I have included a minimally working example. If the example doesn't work for you, there's a problem. If it does, the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I appreciate the work you took. I cloned the repo and after navigating to login I get a `Bad request` response. I tried to log `flashJSONString` and it logs an empty object

Comment: @Maramal did you check the response header and/or cookies, per the README? Remember that there is already a call to `req.flash()` in there, and reading the flash unsets it.

Comment: "Bad request" is expected with that code, since it automatically rejects any authentication attempt

Comment: The `flash-object` cookie and the `x-flash-object` header are empty.

Comment: @Maramal did you follow the instructions ***exactly***? You must load `localhost:9090/login` and *then* **reload it** to get the flash message to appear. The first request triggers the auth, the failure and the flash message getting pushed into the session.  The second time the flash message is caught by the middleware, set in the cookie and returned in a header.

Comment: I've cloned the git repo and tested against a browser in guest mode just in case. It's still working.

Comment: I can make a foolproof one but it will be substantially harder to understand the code

Comment: I may not be the best developer but I understand this code. But, since I already spent that reputation I will give it to you cause you created a repo and tried hard to explain to me like I was an idiot, I appreciate that...

Comment: I have to say that I maybe overcomplicated this. I just referred to `req.flash('error')[0]` and it worked great.

Comment: @Maramal thanks, hope it was able to help you somewhat